# Apply sorting on field in foreign key django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have three models:

```
Class Book(models.Model):
book_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
author = models.Foreignkey('author', on_delete=models.cascade)

Class Author(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
addr = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Class Bookinfo(models.Model):
book = models.ForeignKey('book', on_delete=models.cascade)
page_number = models.IntegerField()
```

Serializers are:

```
Class bookserializer(modelserializer):
Class Meta:
    Model= book
    Fields = ("__all__")

Class authorserializer(modelserializer):
Class Meta:
    Model= author
    Fields = ("__all__")

Class bookinfoserializer(modelserializer):
Class Meta:
    Model= bookinfo
    Fields = ("__all__")
    Depth=2
```

Viewset:

```
Class Bookinfoviewset(viewsets.modelviewset):
Queryset= bookinfo.objects.all()
Serializer_class= bookinfoserializer
```

In the response I get the nested values:

```
{
    Book_id:{
        Book_name:
        Author_id: {
            Name:
            Addr:
        }
    },
    Page_number:
}
```

In the backend I am using PageNumberPagination , searchfilter and ordering.

In the book info view, I want to apply ordering on book_name which is inside book_id which is a foreign key.

How to do that without affecting filter and pagination?

And is there any way to get the fields in foreign key directly in main response like:

```
{   
    Book_name:

    Name:
    Addr:
    Page_number
}
```

I am using python 3.5 django 2.2.9.

Answer (score 2):

In `Bookinfoviewset` add:

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
    queryset = super(Bookinfoviewset, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
    return queryset.order_by("book__book_name")
```

A more elegant alternative would be to add to `Bookinfoviewset`:

```
ordering_fields = ("book__book_name")
ordering = ("book__book_name")
```

But not sure if this works. Let me know and I will update the answer.

Comment: Hey, I did try this but it did not work.